# Want to get the textbox value and create a link from it

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, textbox, mailmessage

I am working on a Work Order Management system, where a user creates a work order, hits the insert button, and after validating the fields I am sending an email.

In the body of the email I would like for the value from a textbox to be clickable via a link (the value is the Work Order Number)

```
 mm.Body = "WorkOrderNumber" + ": &nbsp;" + 
"<a href=\"http://someserver/WorkOrderMgnt/ViewAllWorkOrders.aspx\"></a>"
+TextBox13.Text 
+"<-Click on the Work Order Number"
    mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

I don't get a link to click in the email.  What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should learn how the html anchor element works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, your output is this:

> WorkOrderNumber: <-Click on the Work Order Number

Your hyperlink doesn't output anything to click.

This

```
mm.Body = "WorkOrderNumber" + ": &nbsp;" + 
    "<a href=\"http://someserver/WorkOrderMgnt/ViewAllWorkOrders.aspx\"></a>"
    +TextBox13.Text 
    +"<-Click on the Work Order Number"
```

Needs to include the work order number inside the `<a></a>` tags.

```
mm.Body = "WorkOrderNumber" + ": &nbsp;" + 
    "<a href=\"http://someserver/WorkOrderMgnt/ViewAllWorkOrders.aspx\">" 
    + TextBox13.Text + "</a>"
    + "<-Click on the Work Order Number"
```